# How to cut each page of a PDF or DJVU file into halves?

Tags: pdf, djvu

Say I have a book (either pdf or djvu format) where every page looks like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/EeRMY.png]

Is there any way to cut separate the two pages? I want to print things on A4 paper, but scaling it down by a factor of two sometimes makes the text difficult to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [BRISS.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/briss/) It lets you hand-select multiple regions of each page to divide into new pages.

Comment: Thanks! It's a shame that this doesn't work for DJVU files though!